# Share Session between PHP4(mod_php) and PHP5(cgi)

Tags: php

I'm split as to whether this is an SO question or a SF question, so I'm starting here.

We have a legacy application running under PHP 4 (don't ask), and some other code we need to run under PHP 5.

Session data that is set on the PHP 4 side doesn't seem to be visible/present when running code on the PHP 5/cgi side.

I'm doing a `session_start`, adding some session data under PHP 4, and then doing a `var_dump` of the session from PHP 5 and `$_SESSION` is `null`.

Has anyone got this working?

Environment:

- Apache 2.2.x
- PHP 4.4.9 (mod_php)
- PHP 5.1.3 (cgi)
- Centos 5.6

Comment: It seems to me porting the legacy app to PHP 5 would be far less trouble than this.  Besides, PHP 4 was EOL'd years ago and having it on a live system is a tremendous security risk. Also, you're even using a vastly out-of-date version of PHP 5.  I'd recommend upgrading your software stack, ditching PHP 4 and fixing whatever issues are preventing your script from running in PHP 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, have you verified that the [session.save_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path) is the same for both versions of PHP? You can get/set it with [`session_save_path()`](http://php.net/session_save_path).

Second, are you sure both PHP instances are using the same session ID, or is each version generating its own session ID? You can get/set it with [`session_id()`](http://php.net/session_id). If they aren't, verify that the [session.name](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name) is the same, or else they might be trying to load the session ID from different cookies. (Can be get/set with [`session_name()`](http://php.net/session_name).)

Even if both of the above match, I don't know whether or not they can even share a session like that. If not, you can define a custom session handler for both of them to use. That's how applications that are load-balanced usually work -- they have a custom session handler that saves session info wherever/however they want (usually in a database instead of files), and all servers can access that shared location. See [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/session_set_save_handler).

Comment: Summary:
Yes, that was it.  So, you can in fact run mod_php and php-cgi and share session data.
Detail:  
I checked the phpinfo and the php.ini was the same on both versions.
BUT! Note to others:configuration defaults can be (and were) DIFFERENT between versions.  So, since there was NO value in php.ini for session.save_path, one had one value and one had another.
Thanks!